# Middleware pipeline with UseAuthentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I've below code in `Startup.Configure` function

```
app.UseMiddleware<LogMiddleware>(_loggingLevelSwitch)
 //other code
.ConfigureExceptionHandler(Logger, Configuration)
.UseIdentityServer()
.UseStaticFiles()
.UseMiddleware<ContextSetupMiddleware>()
.ConfigureMvcAndLocalization()
//other code
```

`UseIdentityServer` internally calls `UseAuthentication`

I've setup two schemes cookie and Bearer.

My expectation is after authentication `ContextSetupMiddleware` should be called but it is happening otherwise.

For cookie, I can understand since authentication will be done later and once signin is done it works as expected.

For Bearer, I think it should be part of pipeline since we add a scheme to authenticationbuilder.

---

**Update:**

Made defaultscheme as "Bearer" it started working as I wanted.

However the website has AccountLogin screen (cookie based Auth) and some RestAPI's (JWT based Auth).

Is there a way cookie based authentication is only applicable on AccountLogin screen. I can't add `[Authorize]` since it is login scree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually by design. The default scheme will override if at any middleware it  is required then use `context.AuthenticateAsync()`.

In my case, in `ContextSetupMiddleware` just call `context.AuthenticateAsyc()` and authentication done.